# papaya DICOM viewer, moving slice not working, When it's same

Tags: javascript, dicom, viewer, medical, papaya

I have an array that contains list DICOM slices.

```
var data = [["MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740","MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740","MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.741","MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740","MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.742"]];
params["images"] = dataI
```

I have 5 slices in my array. When I click `+` `-` buttons I can see only three slices in the viewer. Remaining two slices not visible. Sometimes the last slice coming first.

For an example, The 10 images having the same file name. First, the count `z` show 10. And When I click `+` `-` buttons, It should move one by one all 10 images.

[PAPAYA VIEWER](https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya)

**DICOM Attribute values**

First Slice MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740

```html
0002 0000 200
0002 0001 (#00)(#01)
0002 0002 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
0002 0003 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740
0002 0010 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1
0002 0012 1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.5.4
0002 0013 OFFIS_DCMTK_354
0008 0000 888
0008 0005 ISO_IR 100
0008 0008 ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\OTHER
0008 0016 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
0008 0018 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740
0008 0020 20160719
0008 0021 20160719
0008 0022 20160719
0008 0023 20160719
0008 0030 095331
0008 0031 100408
0008 0032 100408
0008 0033 100408
0008 0050 0010277637
0008 0060 MR
0008 0070 GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS
0008 0080 T S G H
0008 0090 
0008 1010 GEHCGEHC
0008 1030 BRAIN
0008 103E STROKE DWI AUTODIFF
0008 1070 YCC
0008 1090 Signa HDxt
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.1
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.338
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.3
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.337
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828229.964
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828229.965
0009 0000 150
0009 0010 GEMS_IDEN_01
0009 1002 GEHC
0009 1004 SIGNA
0009 1027 1468922648
0009 1030 GEHC
0009 1031 9999
0009 10E3 1.2.840.113619.1.244.5.3596.11861950
0009 10E7 -488345165
0009 10E9 1468922648
0010 0000 96
0010 0010 G72305/TZAO.W.D.
0010 0020 2810839
0010 0030 19500527
0010 0040 M
0010 1010 066Y
0010 1030 69
0010 21B0 
0018 0000 482
0018 0020 EP\SE
0018 0021 NONE
0018 0022 EPI_GEMS\FILTERED_GEMS\ACC_GEMS\PFF
0018 0023 2D
0018 0025 N
0018 0050 5
0018 0080 9700
0018 0081 72.7
0018 0082 0
0018 0083 6
0018 0084 63.857878
0018 0085 1H
0018 0086 1
0018 0087 1.5
0018 0088 5
0018 0091 1
0018 0093 100
0018 0094 100
0018 0095 1953.12
0018 1000 000000000000GEHC
0018 1020 15\LX\MR Software release:15.0_M4A_0947.a
0018 1030 2810839/5
0018 1088 0
0018 1090 0
0018 1094 0
0018 1100 240
0018 1250 8HRBRAIN
0018 1310 128\0\0\128
0018 1312 COL
0018 1314 90
0018 1315 N
0018 1316 0.0723413
0018 5100 HFS
0019 0000 1164
0019 0010 GEMS_ACQU_01
0019 100F 317.600006
0019 1011 0
0019 1012 0
0019 1017 16
0019 1018 S
0019 1019 69.2263
0019 101A I
0019 101B -50.7021
0019 101E 240.000000
0019 105A 242500000.0000000000
0019 107D 0
0019 107E 1
0019 107F 0.000000
0019 1081 1
0019 1084 0.144683
0019 1087 0.000000
0019 1088 0
0019 108A 13
0019 108B 12
0019 108D 0
0019 108F 1
0019 1090 0
0019 1091 0.000000
0019 1092 0
0019 1093 638578780
0019 1094 143
0019 1095 13
0019 1096 12
0019 1097 65
0019 109B 1
0019 109C epi2
0019 109D 20100224074649
0019 109E EPI2
0019 109F 3
0019 10A0 0
0019 10A1 0
0019 10A2 7168
0019 10A3 0
0019 10A4 0
0019 10A7 1.000000
0019 10A8 0.000000
0019 10A9 0.000000
0019 10AA 0.000000
0019 10AB 0.000000
0019 10AC 0.000000
0019 10AD 0.000000
0019 10AE 0.000000
0019 10AF 0.000000
0019 10B0 0.000000
0019 10B1 0.000000
0019 10B2 0.000000
0019 10B3 0.000000
0019 10B4 0.000000
0019 10B5 0.000000
0019 10B6 0.000000
0019 10B7 0.000000
0019 10B8 0.000000
0019 10B9 0.000000
0019 10BA 0.000000
0019 10BB 0.000000
0019 10BC 0.000000
0019 10BD 0.000000
0019 10BE 0.000000
0019 10C0 0
0019 10C2 9990
0019 10C3 9990
0019 10C4 9990
0019 10C5 9990
0019 10C6 9990
0019 10C7 9990
0019 10C8 0
0019 10C9 0
0019 10CA 0
0019 10CB 0
0019 10CC 0
0019 10CD 0
0019 10CE 2
0019 10CF 0
0019 10D2 0
0019 10D3 
0019 10D5 3
0019 10D7 0
0019 10D8 0
0019 10D9 0.000000
0019 10DF 0.000000
0019 10E0 0.000000
0019 10E2 0.000000
0019 10F2 0
0019 10F9 143
0020 0000 406
0020 000D 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.341
0020 000E 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.353
0020 0010 27729
0020 0011 5
0020 0012 1
0020 0013 5
0020 0032 -111.106\-157.375\53.5646
0020 0037 0.998302\0.0582299\-0.00167855\-0.0582594\0.997705\-0.0345162
0020 0052 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.340
0020 0060 
0020 1002 50
0020 1040 
0020 1041 49.2382164
0020 9056 1
0020 9057 5
0021 0000 298
0021 0010 GEMS_RELA_01
0021 1035 1
0021 1036 2
0021 1037 16
0021 104F 25
0021 1050 0
0021 1051 0.000000
0021 1052 0.000000
0021 1053 0.000000
0021 1056 0
0021 1057 0
0021 1058 0
0021 1059 0
0021 105A 7
0021 105B 0.000000
0021 105C 0.000000
0021 105D 0.000000
0021 105E 0.000000
0021 105F 0.000000
0021 1081 0
0021 1082 0
0021 1083 0
0021 1084 0
0023 0000 58
0023 0010 GEMS_STDY_01
0023 1070 0.0000000000
0023 1074 0
0023 107D 0
0025 0000 992
0025 0010 GEMS_SERS_01
0025 1006 0
0025 1007 50
0025 1010 0
0025 1011 1
0025 1014 0
0025 1017 0
0025 1018 0
0025 1019 50
0025 101A GEHCGEHC
0025 101B [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0027 0000 150
0027 0010 GEMS_IMAG_01
0027 1006 0
0027 1010 0
0027 1030 
0027 1031 1
0027 1032 0
0027 1033 1140850688
0027 1035 16
0027 1040 S
0027 1041 49.2382164001
0027 1060 128.0000000000
0027 1061 128.0000000000
0027 1062 6.0000000000
0028 0000 156
0028 0002 1
0028 0004 MONOCHROME2
0028 0010 256
0028 0011 256
0028 0030 0.9375\0.9375
0028 0100 16
0028 0101 16
0028 0102 15
0028 0103 1
0028 0106 0
0028 0107 706
0028 1050 353
0028 1051 706
0029 0000 102
0029 0010 GEMS_IMPS_01
0029 1015 0
0029 1016 0
0029 1017 0
0029 1018 0
0029 1026 2
0029 1034 16384
0029 1035 0
0040 0000 34
0040 0253 MR1468922335
0040 0254 BRAIN
0043 0000 7028
0043 0010 GEMS_PARM_01
0043 1001 5
0043 1002 -1
0043 1003 1
0043 1004 -11
0043 1006 1
0043 1007 0
0043 1008 0
0043 1009 0
0043 100A 1
0043 100B 0.000000
0043 100C 100.000000
0043 100D 74.660004
0043 100E 60.250000
0043 1010 0
0043 101C 0
0043 101D 0
0043 1028 MR Recon <0>(#00)/27729/5/1(#00)(#08)AU(#96)(#E7)5`(#08)(#90)(#BB)g(#09)@*jY(#80)%(#7C)Y(#E0)!(#97)(#08)(#04)AU(#96),AU(#96)8AU(#96)(#7E)r-(#08)(#7C)(#BB)g(#09)V(#13)(#97)(#08)(#96)(#01)(#00)(#00)(#E0)!(#97)(#08)
0043 1029 [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0043 102A [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0043 102C 696
0043 102D p+
0043 102E 
0043 102F 0
0043 1030 15
0043 1032 2
0043 1033 0.0000000000
0043 1034 0
0043 1035 0
0043 1036 0
0043 1037 0
0043 1038 0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000
0043 1039 1000\8\0\0
0043 1060 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
0043 1061 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.341
0043 1062 27729
0043 106F 0\0\0\2
0043 107D 0
0043 1080 INVIcjclaEADGQDST8IowW0EECdjyZvk\c600000012d07c0f
0043 1081 GE_HDx 8HRBrain
0043 1082 SRMode=150\GCoilType=3\gradientAmp=8916\lineFreq=60\RFampType=10
0043 1083 0.5\1
0043 1084 10000\7\2\1\generic\YES\ASSET
0043 1088 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.344
0043 1089 FDA\IEC_FIRST_LEVEL\IEC_FIRST_LEVEL
0043 108A COL
0043 1090 WHOLE_BODY_6_MIN\LOCAL_PEAK_6_MIN\PARTIAL_BODY_6MIN
0043 1091 0.07234\0.144683\0.0723413
0043 1095 TG/s1
0043 1096 RESEARCH
0043 1097 2\1\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\100\0\0\rev=1;a=75;b=2;c=32;d=8;e=3;f=2;g=0;h=0
0043 1098 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.344
0043 109A 1
7FE0 0000 131084
7FE0 0010 [Binary Pixel Data]
```

Second Slice MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.741

```html
0002 0000 200
0002 0001 (#00)(#01)
0002 0002 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
0002 0003 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.741
0002 0010 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1
0002 0012 1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.5.4
0002 0013 OFFIS_DCMTK_354
0008 0000 888
0008 0005 ISO_IR 100
0008 0008 ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\OTHER
0008 0016 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
0008 0018 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.741
0008 0020 20160719
0008 0021 20160719
0008 0022 20160719
0008 0023 20160719
0008 0030 095331
0008 0031 100408
0008 0032 100408
0008 0033 100408
0008 0050 0010277637
0008 0060 MR
0008 0070 GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS
0008 0080 T S G H
0008 0090 
0008 1010 GEHCGEHC
0008 1030 BRAIN
0008 103E STROKE DWI AUTODIFF
0008 1070 YCC
0008 1090 Signa HDxt
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.1
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.338
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.3
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.337
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828229.964
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828229.965
0009 0000 150
0009 0010 GEMS_IDEN_01
0009 1002 GEHC
0009 1004 SIGNA
0009 1027 1468922648
0009 1030 GEHC
0009 1031 9999
0009 10E3 1.2.840.113619.1.244.5.3596.11861950
0009 10E7 -488345165
0009 10E9 1468922648
0010 0000 96
0010 0010 G72305/TZAO.W.D.
0010 0020 2810839
0010 0030 19500527
0010 0040 M
0010 1010 066Y
0010 1030 69
0010 21B0 
0018 0000 482
0018 0020 EP\SE
0018 0021 NONE
0018 0022 EPI_GEMS\FILTERED_GEMS\ACC_GEMS\PFF
0018 0023 2D
0018 0025 N
0018 0050 5
0018 0080 9700
0018 0081 72.7
0018 0082 0
0018 0083 6
0018 0084 63.857878
0018 0085 1H
0018 0086 1
0018 0087 1.5
0018 0088 5
0018 0091 1
0018 0093 100
0018 0094 100
0018 0095 1953.12
0018 1000 000000000000GEHC
0018 1020 15\LX\MR Software release:15.0_M4A_0947.a
0018 1030 2810839/5
0018 1088 0
0018 1090 0
0018 1094 0
0018 1100 240
0018 1250 8HRBRAIN
0018 1310 128\0\0\128
0018 1312 COL
0018 1314 90
0018 1315 N
0018 1316 0.0723413
0018 5100 HFS
0019 0000 1164
0019 0010 GEMS_ACQU_01
0019 100F 317.600006
0019 1011 0
0019 1012 0
0019 1017 16
0019 1018 S
0019 1019 69.2263
0019 101A I
0019 101B -50.7021
0019 101E 240.000000
0019 105A 242500000.0000000000
0019 107D 0
0019 107E 1
0019 107F 0.000000
0019 1081 1
0019 1084 0.144683
0019 1087 0.000000
0019 1088 0
0019 108A 13
0019 108B 12
0019 108D 0
0019 108F 1
0019 1090 0
0019 1091 0.000000
0019 1092 0
0019 1093 638578780
0019 1094 143
0019 1095 13
0019 1096 12
0019 1097 65
0019 109B 1
0019 109C epi2
0019 109D 20100224074649
0019 109E EPI2
0019 109F 3
0019 10A0 0
0019 10A1 0
0019 10A2 7168
0019 10A3 0
0019 10A4 0
0019 10A7 1.000000
0019 10A8 0.000000
0019 10A9 0.000000
0019 10AA 0.000000
0019 10AB 0.000000
0019 10AC 0.000000
0019 10AD 0.000000
0019 10AE 0.000000
0019 10AF 0.000000
0019 10B0 0.000000
0019 10B1 0.000000
0019 10B2 0.000000
0019 10B3 0.000000
0019 10B4 0.000000
0019 10B5 0.000000
0019 10B6 0.000000
0019 10B7 0.000000
0019 10B8 0.000000
0019 10B9 0.000000
0019 10BA 0.000000
0019 10BB 0.000000
0019 10BC 0.000000
0019 10BD 0.000000
0019 10BE 0.000000
0019 10C0 0
0019 10C2 9990
0019 10C3 9990
0019 10C4 9990
0019 10C5 9990
0019 10C6 9990
0019 10C7 9990
0019 10C8 0
0019 10C9 0
0019 10CA 0
0019 10CB 0
0019 10CC 0
0019 10CD 0
0019 10CE 2
0019 10CF 0
0019 10D2 0
0019 10D3 
0019 10D5 3
0019 10D7 0
0019 10D8 0
0019 10D9 0.000000
0019 10DF 0.000000
0019 10E0 0.000000
0019 10E2 0.000000
0019 10F2 0
0019 10F9 143
0020 0000 408
0020 000D 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.341
0020 000E 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.353
0020 0010 27729
0020 0011 5
0020 0012 1
0020 0013 6
0020 0032 -111.104\-157.548\48.5676
0020 0037 0.998302\0.0582299\-0.00167853\-0.0582594\0.997705\-0.0345162
0020 0052 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.340
0020 0060 
0020 1002 50
0020 1040 
0020 1041 44.24120331
0020 9056 1
0020 9057 6
0021 0000 298
0021 0010 GEMS_RELA_01
0021 1035 1
0021 1036 2
0021 1037 16
0021 104F 25
0021 1050 0
0021 1051 0.000000
0021 1052 0.000000
0021 1053 0.000000
0021 1056 0
0021 1057 0
0021 1058 0
0021 1059 0
0021 105A 7
0021 105B 0.000000
0021 105C 0.000000
0021 105D 0.000000
0021 105E 0.000000
0021 105F 0.000000
0021 1081 0
0021 1082 0
0021 1083 0
0021 1084 0
0023 0000 58
0023 0010 GEMS_STDY_01
0023 1070 0.0000000000
0023 1074 0
0023 107D 0
0025 0000 992
0025 0010 GEMS_SERS_01
0025 1006 0
0025 1007 50
0025 1010 0
0025 1011 1
0025 1014 0
0025 1017 0
0025 1018 0
0025 1019 50
0025 101A GEHCGEHC
0025 101B [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0027 0000 150
0027 0010 GEMS_IMAG_01
0027 1006 0
0027 1010 0
0027 1030 
0027 1031 1
0027 1032 0
0027 1033 1140850688
0027 1035 16
0027 1040 S
0027 1041 44.2412033081
0027 1060 128.0000000000
0027 1061 128.0000000000
0027 1062 6.0000000000
0028 0000 156
0028 0002 1
0028 0004 MONOCHROME2
0028 0010 256
0028 0011 256
0028 0030 0.9375\0.9375
0028 0100 16
0028 0101 16
0028 0102 15
0028 0103 1
0028 0106 0
0028 0107 698
0028 1050 349
0028 1051 698
0029 0000 102
0029 0010 GEMS_IMPS_01
0029 1015 0
0029 1016 0
0029 1017 0
0029 1018 0
0029 1026 2
0029 1034 16384
0029 1035 0
0040 0000 34
0040 0253 MR1468922335
0040 0254 BRAIN
0043 0000 7028
0043 0010 GEMS_PARM_01
0043 1001 5
0043 1002 -1
0043 1003 1
0043 1004 -11
0043 1006 1
0043 1007 0
0043 1008 0
0043 1009 0
0043 100A 1
0043 100B 0.000000
0043 100C 100.000000
0043 100D 74.660004
0043 100E 60.250000
0043 1010 0
0043 101C 0
0043 101D 0
0043 1028 MR Recon <0>(#00)/27729/5/1(#00)(#A8)(#B1)(#CE)y(#E7)5`(#08)(#90)(#BB)g(#09)@(#FD)lY(#80)(#80)(#86)Y(#E0)!(#97)(#08)(#A4)(#B1)(#CE)y(#CC)(#B1)(#CE)y(#D8)(#B1)(#CE)y(#7E)r-(#08)(#7C)(#BB)g(#09)V(#13)(#97)(#08)(#96)(#01)(#00)(#00)(#E0)!(#97)(#08)
0043 1029 [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0043 102A [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0043 102C 696
0043 102D p+
0043 102E 
0043 102F 0
0043 1030 15
0043 1032 2
0043 1033 0.0000000000
0043 1034 0
0043 1035 0
0043 1036 0
0043 1037 0
0043 1038 0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000
0043 1039 1000\8\0\0
0043 1060 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
0043 1061 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.341
0043 1062 27729
0043 106F 0\0\0\2
0043 107D 0
0043 1080 INVIcjclaEADGQDST8IowW0EECdjyZvk\c600000012d07c0f
0043 1081 GE_HDx 8HRBrain
0043 1082 SRMode=150\GCoilType=3\gradientAmp=8916\lineFreq=60\RFampType=10
0043 1083 0.5\1
0043 1084 10000\7\2\1\generic\YES\ASSET
0043 1088 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.344
0043 1089 FDA\IEC_FIRST_LEVEL\IEC_FIRST_LEVEL
0043 108A COL
0043 1090 WHOLE_BODY_6_MIN\LOCAL_PEAK_6_MIN\PARTIAL_BODY_6MIN
0043 1091 0.07234\0.144683\0.0723413
0043 1095 TG/s1
0043 1096 RESEARCH
0043 1097 2\1\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\100\0\0\rev=1;a=75;b=2;c=32;d=8;e=3;f=2;g=0;h=0
0043 1098 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.344
0043 109A 1
7FE0 0000 131084
7FE0 0010 [Binary Pixel Data]
```

Third Slice MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740

```html
0002 0000 200
0002 0001 (#00)(#01)
0002 0002 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
0002 0003 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.742
0002 0010 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1
0002 0012 1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.5.4
0002 0013 OFFIS_DCMTK_354
0008 0000 888
0008 0005 ISO_IR 100
0008 0008 ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\OTHER
0008 0016 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
0008 0018 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.742
0008 0020 20160719
0008 0021 20160719
0008 0022 20160719
0008 0023 20160719
0008 0030 095331
0008 0031 100408
0008 0032 100408
0008 0033 100408
0008 0050 0010277637
0008 0060 MR
0008 0070 GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS
0008 0080 T S G H
0008 0090 
0008 1010 GEHCGEHC
0008 1030 BRAIN
0008 103E STROKE DWI AUTODIFF
0008 1070 YCC
0008 1090 Signa HDxt
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.1
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.338
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.3
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.337
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828229.964
>0008 1150 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
>0008 1155 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828229.965
0009 0000 150
0009 0010 GEMS_IDEN_01
0009 1002 GEHC
0009 1004 SIGNA
0009 1027 1468922648
0009 1030 GEHC
0009 1031 9999
0009 10E3 1.2.840.113619.1.244.5.3596.11861950
0009 10E7 -488345165
0009 10E9 1468922648
0010 0000 96
0010 0010 G72305/TZAO.W.D.
0010 0020 2810839
0010 0030 19500527
0010 0040 M
0010 1010 066Y
0010 1030 69
0010 21B0 
0018 0000 482
0018 0020 EP\SE
0018 0021 NONE
0018 0022 EPI_GEMS\FILTERED_GEMS\ACC_GEMS\PFF
0018 0023 2D
0018 0025 N
0018 0050 5
0018 0080 9700
0018 0081 72.7
0018 0082 0
0018 0083 6
0018 0084 63.857878
0018 0085 1H
0018 0086 1
0018 0087 1.5
0018 0088 5
0018 0091 1
0018 0093 100
0018 0094 100
0018 0095 1953.12
0018 1000 000000000000GEHC
0018 1020 15\LX\MR Software release:15.0_M4A_0947.a
0018 1030 2810839/5
0018 1088 0
0018 1090 0
0018 1094 0
0018 1100 240
0018 1250 8HRBRAIN
0018 1310 128\0\0\128
0018 1312 COL
0018 1314 90
0018 1315 N
0018 1316 0.0723413
0018 5100 HFS
0019 0000 1164
0019 0010 GEMS_ACQU_01
0019 100F 317.600006
0019 1011 0
0019 1012 0
0019 1017 16
0019 1018 S
0019 1019 69.2263
0019 101A I
0019 101B -50.7021
0019 101E 240.000000
0019 105A 242500000.0000000000
0019 107D 0
0019 107E 1
0019 107F 0.000000
0019 1081 1
0019 1084 0.144683
0019 1087 0.000000
0019 1088 0
0019 108A 13
0019 108B 12
0019 108D 0
0019 108F 1
0019 1090 0
0019 1091 0.000000
0019 1092 0
0019 1093 638578780
0019 1094 143
0019 1095 13
0019 1096 12
0019 1097 65
0019 109B 1
0019 109C epi2
0019 109D 20100224074649
0019 109E EPI2
0019 109F 3
0019 10A0 0
0019 10A1 0
0019 10A2 7168
0019 10A3 0
0019 10A4 0
0019 10A7 1.000000
0019 10A8 0.000000
0019 10A9 0.000000
0019 10AA 0.000000
0019 10AB 0.000000
0019 10AC 0.000000
0019 10AD 0.000000
0019 10AE 0.000000
0019 10AF 0.000000
0019 10B0 0.000000
0019 10B1 0.000000
0019 10B2 0.000000
0019 10B3 0.000000
0019 10B4 0.000000
0019 10B5 0.000000
0019 10B6 0.000000
0019 10B7 0.000000
0019 10B8 0.000000
0019 10B9 0.000000
0019 10BA 0.000000
0019 10BB 0.000000
0019 10BC 0.000000
0019 10BD 0.000000
0019 10BE 0.000000
0019 10C0 0
0019 10C2 9990
0019 10C3 9990
0019 10C4 9990
0019 10C5 9990
0019 10C6 9990
0019 10C7 9990
0019 10C8 0
0019 10C9 0
0019 10CA 0
0019 10CB 0
0019 10CC 0
0019 10CD 0
0019 10CE 2
0019 10CF 0
0019 10D2 0
0019 10D3 
0019 10D5 3
0019 10D7 0
0019 10D8 0
0019 10D9 0.000000
0019 10DF 0.000000
0019 10E0 0.000000
0019 10E2 0.000000
0019 10F2 0
0019 10F9 143
0020 0000 406
0020 000D 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.341
0020 000E 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.353
0020 0010 27729
0020 0011 5
0020 0012 1
0020 0013 7
0020 0032 -111.103\-157.721\43.5706
0020 0037 0.998302\0.05823\-0.00167855\-0.0582594\0.997705\-0.0345162
0020 0052 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.340
0020 0060 
0020 1002 50
0020 1040 
0020 1041 39.24419022
0020 9056 1
0020 9057 7
0021 0000 298
0021 0010 GEMS_RELA_01
0021 1035 1
0021 1036 2
0021 1037 16
0021 104F 25
0021 1050 0
0021 1051 0.000000
0021 1052 0.000000
0021 1053 0.000000
0021 1056 0
0021 1057 0
0021 1058 0
0021 1059 0
0021 105A 7
0021 105B 0.000000
0021 105C 0.000000
0021 105D 0.000000
0021 105E 0.000000
0021 105F 0.000000
0021 1081 0
0021 1082 0
0021 1083 0
0021 1084 0
0023 0000 58
0023 0010 GEMS_STDY_01
0023 1070 0.0000000000
0023 1074 0
0023 107D 0
0025 0000 992
0025 0010 GEMS_SERS_01
0025 1006 0
0025 1007 50
0025 1010 0
0025 1011 1
0025 1014 0
0025 1017 0
0025 1018 0
0025 1019 50
0025 101A GEHCGEHC
0025 101B [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0027 0000 150
0027 0010 GEMS_IMAG_01
0027 1006 0
0027 1010 0
0027 1030 
0027 1031 1
0027 1032 0
0027 1033 1140850688
0027 1035 16
0027 1040 S
0027 1041 39.2441902161
0027 1060 128.0000000000
0027 1061 128.0000000000
0027 1062 6.0000000000
0028 0000 156
0028 0002 1
0028 0004 MONOCHROME2
0028 0010 256
0028 0011 256
0028 0030 0.9375\0.9375
0028 0100 16
0028 0101 16
0028 0102 15
0028 0103 1
0028 0106 0
0028 0107 706
0028 1050 353
0028 1051 706
0029 0000 102
0029 0010 GEMS_IMPS_01
0029 1015 0
0029 1016 0
0029 1017 0
0029 1018 0
0029 1026 2
0029 1034 16384
0029 1035 0
0040 0000 34
0040 0253 MR1468922335
0040 0254 BRAIN
0043 0000 7028
0043 0010 GEMS_PARM_01
0043 1001 5
0043 1002 -1
0043 1003 1
0043 1004 -11
0043 1006 1
0043 1007 0
0043 1008 0
0043 1009 0
0043 100A 1
0043 100B 0.000000
0043 100C 100.000000
0043 100D 74.660004
0043 100E 60.250000
0043 1010 0
0043 101C 0
0043 101D 0
0043 1028 MR Recon <0>(#00)/27729/5/1(#00)h(#B1)(#CA)y(#E7)5`(#08)(#90)(#BB)g(#09)(#90)(#AA)iYPQzY(#E0)!(#97)(#08)d(#B1)(#CA)y(#8C)(#B1)(#CA)y(#98)(#B1)(#CA)y(#7E)r-(#08)(#7C)(#BB)g(#09)V(#13)(#97)(#08)(#96)(#01)(#00)(#00)(#E0)!(#97)(#08)
0043 1029 [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0043 102A [dataset link is not loaded to memory]
0043 102C 696
0043 102D p+
0043 102E 
0043 102F 0
0043 1030 15
0043 1032 2
0043 1033 0.0000000000
0043 1034 0
0043 1035 0
0043 1036 0
0043 1037 0
0043 1038 0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000\0.0000000000
0043 1039 1000\8\0\0
0043 1060 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
0043 1061 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.341
0043 1062 27729
0043 106F 0\0\0\2
0043 107D 0
0043 1080 INVIcjclaEADGQDST8IowW0EECdjyZvk\c600000012d07c0f
0043 1081 GE_HDx 8HRBrain
0043 1082 SRMode=150\GCoilType=3\gradientAmp=8916\lineFreq=60\RFampType=10
0043 1083 0.5\1
0043 1084 10000\7\2\1\generic\YES\ASSET
0043 1088 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.344
0043 1089 FDA\IEC_FIRST_LEVEL\IEC_FIRST_LEVEL
0043 108A COL
0043 1090 WHOLE_BODY_6_MIN\LOCAL_PEAK_6_MIN\PARTIAL_BODY_6MIN
0043 1091 0.07234\0.144683\0.0723413
0043 1095 TG/s1
0043 1096 RESEARCH
0043 1097 2\1\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\1.5 0.2 0.2 2.0 64 0.4 1.05\100\0\0\rev=1;a=75;b=2;c=32;d=8;e=3;f=2;g=0;h=0
0043 1098 1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.27321.1468828168.344
0043 109A 1
7FE0 0000 131084
7FE0 0010 [Binary Pixel Data]
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

> I can see only three slices in the viewer.
>
> "MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.**740**",
>   "MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.**740**",
>   "MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.741",
>   "MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.**740**",
>   "MR.1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.742"

Three of the slices are the same (.740).  So there's only three unique slices which is why it only shows those three.

> The 10 images having the same file name.

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Are they really the same file?  It won't simply stack the files on top of each other.  It will look at their metadata and determine if they are part of the same series (presumably removing duplicates), then order them according to their position relative to one another.

Comment: I want to load files like this (  * .740, *.740, *.740, *.741, *.742, *.742)

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with whiskeyspider. I am quite sure the root cause for your problem is found in the DICOM headers.

I do not know papaya but if it behaves like virtually all other viewers in the world, it will scroll through the slices if:

- all slices belong to the same patient (0010,0020) - Patient ID, maybe other patient attributes like name (0010,0010), birthdate (0010,0030) and sex (0010,0040) are considered. These attributes must be identical for all slices
- all slices belong to the same study (0020,000D) - Study Instance UID is identical for all slices
- all slices belong to the same series (00020,000E) - Series Instance UID is identical for all slices
- each slice is different from the others, i.e. it is a unique instance - (0008,0018) SOP Instance UID is different in each slice

A good viewer does not use the filenames but only the DICOM header attributes for determining assignment of the image (to patient, study, series) and its uniqueness and order in the series stack. I think this is the case for papaya.

So my guess is:

- Patient, Study and Series attributes *are* identical for all images
- The filenames are constructed from (0008,0060) Modality (="MR") and (0008,0018) SOP Instance UID.
- Since three images have an identical SOP Instance UID (1.2.840.113619.2.244.3596.11861950.26703.1468828230.740), papaya correctly considers them identical and discards the duplicates after loading them
- This results in three unique images (*.740, *.741, *.742) which is exactly what you observe when scrolling through the series.

So if my guess is right your problem is that you do not really have 6 different *images*. Your have 6 different *files*. These are three different images and three copies of image *.740. The copies are correctly discarded by papaya.

Check the attribute values by using a DICOM dump tool of which many are available for free. The output should look like this:

```
[...]
(0010,0010) PN [Sam Goodfellow]                         #  14, 1 PatientName
(0010,0020) LO [999-123-9991]                           #  12, 1 PatientID
(0010,0030) DA [19550902]                               #   8, 1 PatientBirthDate
(0010,0040) CS [M]                                      #   2, 1 PatientSex
(0018,0000) UL 84                                       #   4, 1 GenericGroupLength
(0018,1164) DS [9.62121212121212e-003\9.62121212121212e-003] #  44, 2 ImagerPixelSpacing
[...]
```

Comment: (*.740, *.741, *.741) If I load my file like this, I can see all three slices. But I can see this way in my viewer (*.741, *.740, *.741)

Comment: Can you share the images or even better a DICOM dump of the headers?

Comment: @AshokCharu: This is not the DICOM dump of the image headers I had requested for. I want to check the DICOM header attributes of the images.

Comment: @AshokCharu: I have added my answer accordingly to show you an example of how this would look like.

Comment: @AshokCharu: Please do not send the images. Post a (text) dump of their headers here. Please note that I suspect your problem is related to inter-image-dependencies. I need dumps of ALL images to provide further help.

Comment: @kritzel_sw  I haded three images metadata, please check Or give any idea to do this.

Comment: All images belong to the same patient, study and series. Their sequential numbers range from 5 through 7, so they seem to be neibouring slices. So far, I would suspect that these three images are seen and scrolled by the viewer and the other 2 slices you are missing are duplicates. Please check 0008 0018 SOP Instance UID for uniqueness.